# Hibernate nested obeject

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, persistence

I am trying to save nested object and out of those nested objects i don't want to save one object. How can i achieve this? 
When i am running this i am getting transient exception

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance.
```

I know i am doing something stupid which is not recommended by hibernate.

Scenario:

```
A, B, C, D are four different tables.

Table A  ( field1, field2 , field3[fk to table B])   
Table B  ( field3, field4 , field5 [fk to table C])   
Table C  ( field5, field7 , field8)  
Table D  ( field6, field9 , field3[fk to table B])
```

Objects

A

```
private String field1;   
private String field2;  
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@JoinColumn(name="field3")  
private B b;
```

B

```
private String field3;  
private String field4;    
//Want to save D  
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@JoinColumn(name="field3")    
private List<D> d;         // This is a list of D  
//Dont want to save C  
@OneToOne  
@JoinColumn(name="field5")  
private C c;
```

C

```
private String field5;  
private String field7;     
private String field8;
```

D

```
private String field6;  
private String field9;     
private String field3;
```

Comment: The code where you save objects?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me why you want to do this, but I think it can be done.

1. Get your entity graph in the state you want it to be persisted. This probably means setting the field you don't want saved to null (temporarily).
2. Save/persist.
3. Restore the nulled-out value(s). If you are in a transaction, you may want to detach the entity before restoring the values you don't want persisted.

Like most frameworks, hibernate is awesome when you are following the pattern that hibernate was designed to support. Things can get creepy and painful when you try to do something "weird."

Comment: Beacuse field5 is nullable in Table B and C is an static table.      I tried assigning C as NULL, If i set C as NULL it starts looking for C.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown when you

> "pass a transient instance to a Session method that expects a
>   persistent instance".

Baking a transient instance make sure you have loaded references before passing that transient instance to the save method.  If you don't have persistent references that first save the objects that haven't references to other transient instances.